# Display maps from QGIS in my GUI created using PyQt5

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt, pyqt5

I wish to create a GUI using PyQt5 for an application that displays a map created using QGIS. How do I integrate QGIS and PyQt so that the map I wish to display can be shown in my app?